# Solve for a variable given 3 collinear points

Tags: geometry

> On a plane, the points (v,-3),(2v+1,4) and (-1,1) are collinear, find the value of v.

How can i solve this?, I tried using the gradient formula but its not getting me anywhere in terms of finding the actual value of "v".

Comment: Hint: Find the slopes in terms of $v$ between $(-1,1)$ and each of the other two points. Then solve for the value of $v$ which makes those two slopes equal.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Express that the three points satisfy the equation of a straight line,

$$ax+by+c=0.$$

This is possible when the $3\times3$ system they form is compatible, i.e. when

$$\begin{vmatrix}v&-3&1\\2v+1&4&1\\-1&1&1\end{vmatrix}=0.$$

Solve this equation for $v$.

Answer (score 0):

Any line passing through the point $(-1,1)$ can be written as

$$L: y-1 = m(x+1) $$

Now, you have two variables, $v,m$, and two equations, one from satisfying the line equation at each point

$$ -4 = m(v+1)$$

$$ 3 = m(2v+2)$$

Now, since we are only interested in $v$, use appropriate substitution for $m$ in terms of $v$ to get one equation in $v$

$$-4(2v+2) = 3(v+1)$$

Geomoetrically, this is the same as @quasi's comment, we are simply equating slopes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are right.

The solpe between (v,-3) & (-1,1) = -4/(v+1)

The slope between (2v+1,4) & (-1,1)= 3/2v

Now, as the points are collinear , the slopes will have to be equal. 
So,.   -4/(v+1)= 3/2v
From that you can find that v=-3/11 or 0.272727(approximately)